# How to convert big decimal to varchar in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

Let's say I've a table named **Users** as mentioned below:

```````````
SomeNumber       FName    LName  
``````````       `````    ``````  
1.2345678e+014   John     Doe  
2.2345678e+014   Tony     Stark
```````````

How can I convert `SomeNumber` column to varchar value? Like no e+014 should be displayed in the column. Actual values of SomeNumber column are `123456789JD` and `234567890TS`

I've tried the following but none of them worked.

```
CONVERT(varchar, [SomeNumber])
CAST([SomeNumber] as varchar)
Try_Parse([SomeNumber] as varchar)
```

Expected output should be in this format:

```````````
SomeNumber      FName    LName  
``````````      `````    ``````  
123456789JD     John     Doe  
234567890TS     Tony     Stark
```````````

PS: **`SomeNumber`** column is of the type nvarchar(255)

Comment: Why are you storing it as `nvarchar(255)` in the first place?#

Comment: CAST(@id as varchar(max))

Comment: Data in this table is directly imported from  an excel sheet.  Not all values are like 1.2345678e+014. Only some random records have the data as bigdecimal (1.2345678e+014). And to answer your question, no particular reason.

Comment: you need to go via `float` but best to just fix this on import

Comment: @pascalsanchez didn't work. It still shows the same value.

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm correcting my question. My bad.

Comment: Now your question contains contradictory information. First you say it is like `1.2345678e+014 ` and then like `123456789JD`

Comment: Actual value is 123456789JD. But for some reason, Excel sheet is showing it as 1.2345678e+014. As data is displayed as bigDecimal in excel sheet, the same format is copied to SQL Server table.

Comment: The answer was added by @MartinSmith :) it's work fine by passing via float type. But i think He have reasons about the best way it's to fix import by fixing your column type on your excel worksheet.

Comment: Do you mean that there is a mix of types? Some are entirely numeric and Excel converts them to scientific notation - others contain alpha characters and these are treated as text? Excel won't convert 123456789JD to 1.2345678e+014

Comment: Please add you Excel worksheet because i didn't try too reproduce thoses (123456789JD) as (1.2345678e+014) 

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

Sorry for my first Answer i'have bad read your query.

```
DECLARE @id varchar(max) = '1.2345678e+014' 
select CAST(@id as float)
```

Result : 
123456780000000

Other add :

```
DECLARE @id varchar(max) = '1.2345678e+014' 
select CAST(CAST(CAST(@id as float) AS bigint) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + 'Letters' --Conversion takes place
```